# Group Sites by Groups

Tags: localization, filter, multi-site

We have many country websites on different continents. In the CP we group the sites, where the group has the name of the continent.

Now we want to group the sites in the templates in the same way.

I have this, but it is not giving back the group.

```
{% set allSites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}
{% set allGroups = allSites|group('allSites.group') %}

{% for group, countriesInGroup in allGroups %}
    {{ group }} <br>
    {% for country in countriesInGroup %}
        {{country.language}} <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Site component

#### PHP

```
$groups = Craft::$app->getSites()->getAllGroups();
foreach ($groups as $group){
    echo $group->name;
    foreach ($group->getSites() as $site){
        echo $site->name;
    }
}
```

#### Twig

```
{% set groups = craft.app.getSites().getAllGroups() %}
{% for group in groups %}
    {{ group.name }}
    {% for site in group.getSites() %}
        {{ site.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It will return  all sites of all groups

Comment: Ok, picking up this task again. 
Unfortunately, it's not returning the site that belongs to the groups.

This is my result on your twig code example Robin:
Africa 
Asia 
Australia 
Europe 
North America 
South America